# How to pass an input parameter as test classname in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have to run a specific test through the command prompt. Could you please
clarify how to pass an input parameter as test class name in
testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have `TestNG` in your class path, you can simply run the below command:

`java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml com.example.Foo.testMethod1`

**Make sure you have specified the fully qualified name of the test method.**

You can also have a look to the official `TestNG` [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) to play around the commands to run the test cases.